# np.dot product not possible

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication in `numpy`, but it's not working.

I have the following covariance matrix `L`:

```
[[ 0.04208927  0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.02261722  0.01793027  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.03292572  0.00720304  0.01518221  0.        ]
 [ 0.02629853 -0.00107695  0.00939721  0.01987997]]
```

And the following random variables `future_bch`:

```
            0         1         2         3
0    0.062850 -0.120748  0.016459  0.200652
1    0.015153  0.019969  0.009285  0.075218
..        ...       ...       ...       ...
998 -0.196630  0.083896  0.051008  0.069275
999  0.016146 -0.111402  0.021744  0.045193
```

My code:

```
 corr_ret = np.dot(L, future_bch)
```

And the error is:

```
    corr_ret = np.dot(L, future_bch)
 ValueError: shapes (4,4) and (1000,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1000 (dim 0)
```

EDIT

This works when we use transpose function on the 1000*4 matrix.
each of the rows after the transposition has to be into an array which is not the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to multiply two matrices, the column of the first matrix and the row of the second matrix should be equal.
you are trying to multiply the 4X4 matrix with a 4X1000 one, which isn't possible.
You can read more about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Edit:
it is possible that you initialized the (matrices incorrectly).